# Meaning of で in 敦賀から新大阪まで〈で〉２兆１０００億円かかる予定です

Tags: particle-で, particle-まで

Regarding the construction of a new bullet train line:

> 工事のお金は、[敦賀]{つるが}から新大阪まで**で**２兆１０００億円かかる予定です。
>   The construction cost from 敦賀 to 新大阪 is expected to be (some eye watering amount of money).

I can't understand the function of the で in bold. Can it be omitted? It seems to make sense to me without it.

Comment: But isn't it the straightforward way of [using で](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/verbparticles)?  It is the _construction_ that will take the money, not the line itself, and the construction will take money *by way of* (building the line) from A to B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That で is part of a set phrase `[purpose/item] で [price] かかる` ("to cost [price] **for/to** [purpose]"). You can use に instead of で.

- 1回の通話{で/に}30円かかる。 It takes 30 yen to make one call.
- 1円玉を作るの{で/に}2円かかる。 Making a 1-yen coin costs 2 yen.
- このスマホを製造するのに、CPUで30ドル、バッテリーで10ドルかかっています。
  It costs $30 for the CPU and $10 for the battery to manufacture this smartphone.

In your example, that で can be omitted but it feels more formal and a bit more natural to keep it.

Comment: I've got two quite different answers here. +1 to both of them, but I don't know which to accept.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell you can pretend there is no で there. The meaning is the same.

---

I think its better to tackle all the siblings of まで at the same time.

There is a difference between までで,までに,まで and までは if まで is followed by an action verb. I am almost explaining raw what you can find in 日本語の作文技術〈新版〉 by 本多{ほんだ}勝一{かついち} page 224-225.

He takes the following example:

> 列車が名古屋に着く〈まで・までに・までで・までは〉雑誌を読むのを止めた。

- まで express the fact that an action is continuing. So the sentence with まで means *Up until the train reached Nagoya he continued not to read the magazine*.
- What is before までに express a deadline. That means that the action (読むのを止める) took place before that deadline. Thus the sentence with までに means *He stopped reading the magazine at some point before the train reached Nagoya.
- The point that in time before までで (here, 名古屋に着く) is the **exact end point** of the action. Thus, The sentence with までで means *Exactly when the train reached Nagoya, he stopped reading the magazine.*
- The は of までは is a は of contrast between before and after reaching Nagoya. Thus, the sentence with までは means *Until Nagoya I did not read but after reaching Nagoya* but he probably did read after the train reached Nagoya.

---

Here かかる is not an action verb, so there is no difference in meaning. The only difference is that this で strengthen the fact that 新大坂 is the ending point.

Comment: I've got two quite different answers here. +1 to both of them, but I don't know which to accept.

Comment: @user3856370 My answer is quite generic, it may be useful in other contexts because it explains the difference between made/madeni/madede. On the other side, naruto's directly address your question about で～かかる so I think you should accept his.