# The use of で in a sentence not related to action or means

Tags: particles, particle-で

The particle で typically marks the means of an action, and the location of an action ([[1]](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/particle-de/), [[2]](https://8020japanese.com/particle-de/)).

But why is it used after から, in many sentences such as:

> お時間がない方はまずは、ご相談から**で**大丈夫ですよ 'If you don't have time, it's okay to consult
> with us first.'

http://cowa-highschool.com/category/blog/page/4/

My dictionary doesn't indicate the word からで exists.

I know that the following of two particles is possible (for example に + は: 求職申込みの手続きには、次の方法があります。'There are two ways to apply for a job', [[3]](https://www.hellowork.mhlw.go.jp/member/app_entryguide.html)), so I suppose it is something similar here, but I would like to be sure.

And if it is the case, are this kind of construction (i.e.: Preposition + Particle; Particle + Particle) pervasive in Japanese?

Comment: This may be of help https://www.kanshudo.com/grammar/%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%81%A7

Comment: You'd need to think から and で separately, as in https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/44609/45489

Comment: @sundowner Oh, the serve is to mark register? (formal register)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The で is simple *with* just like the following.

Suppose you are wondering which of iPad and iPad pro to buy, and get the following advice.

- ウェブを見るだけなら、iPadで大丈夫ですよ.
- If you use it just for web-surfing, you should be okay **with** iPad.

ご相談からで parses as (ご相談+から)+で, which literally means *with from consulting*. Essentially it says you can just consult first ("it is okay *with (starting) from consultation*") although I'm not clear about how it reduces the time/requires less time for busy people.

---

A similar thing in English would be something like *from behind*, in the sense that two prepositions are used consecutively (in the example in Japanese, particles as post-position are used consecutively).